# Examining Simple Service and Client Tutorial

Tags: ros, c++, tutorial, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When going through the first part of the tutorial of the subject title, this is what happens in terminal:

warhost@warhost-Latitude-E6400:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server
[ERROR] [1422561896.227835500]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...

It stays there until ^c'd out.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? I did this in C++
Do you need me to post code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202076/examining-simple-service-and-client-tutorial/) by [warhost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21525/warhost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is expected; the "service server" will just sit there waiting for requests from clients. To exercise the server, you'll need to start another terminal window and run client(s) that make requests to the server.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0